# I need to filter this MDX result set

Tags: mdx

I am looking to filter the result set below such that I only show results where Dimension A Value 1 have a count of 1, regardless of the value of count for Dimension A Value 2

```
           Dimension A Value 1     Dimension A Value 2
Entity ID   Count                Count
11              1   
78          1   
90          1   
101         1   
114                                1
118         1   
125         1   
134                                    1
140         1   
161         1   
169         1   
186         1                  2
```

The filtered set would look like

```
    Dimension A Value 1 Dimension A Value 2
Entity ID   Count               Count
11           1  
78           1  
90           1  
101          1  
118          1  
125          1  
140          1  
161          1  
169          1  
186          1                 2
```

the mdx is

```
WITH
SET [~COLUMNS] AS
    {[Dimension A].[Dimension A].[Value 1], [Dimension A].[Dimension A].[Value 2]}
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[Entity].[Entity].[Entity ID].Members}
SELECT
NON EMPTY CrossJoin([~COLUMNS], {[Measures].[Count]}) ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [My Cube]
```

I've been playing around with Filter and NonEmpty but I'm new to MDX and my sql brain is hurting. I suppose this is probably trivial to someone with a lot of MDX under their belt but I'm failing. Be gentle this is my first question

Comment: welcome to SO nooboy: strangely I've just been helping with something very similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a `HAVING` clause:

```
WITH
SET [~COLUMNS] AS
    {
      [Dimension A].[Dimension A].[Value 1], 
      [Dimension A].[Dimension A].[Value 2]
    } 
MEMBER [Measures].[CountValue1] AS   //<<<<this is new <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    (
       [Measures].[Count],
       [Dimension A].[Dimension A].[Value 1]
    )
SELECT
NON EMPTY 
  CrossJoin(
    [~COLUMNS]
  , {[Measures].[Count]}
  ) ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
  [Entity].[Entity].[Entity ID].MEMBERS 
  HAVING [Measures].[CountValue1] = 1    //<<CHANGED TO NEW MEASURE
  ON ROWS
FROM [My Cube];
```

If you can use `HAVING` rather than `FILTER` you will likely see a performance improvement - particularly if your scripts become more complex:
https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2006/01/04/the-having-clause/

Just to be complete the slower `FILTER` version would be this:

```
WITH
SET [~COLUMNS] AS
    {
      [Dimension A].[Dimension A].[Value 1], 
      [Dimension A].[Dimension A].[Value 2]
    } 
//>>>>>> following is new >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
MEMBER [Measures].[CountValueNEW] AS   
    (
       [Measures].[Count],
       [Dimension A].[Dimension A].[Value 1]
    )
SELECT
NON EMPTY 
    [~COLUMNS]
   *{[Measures].[Count]}
ON 0,
NON EMPTY 
FILTER(
  [Entity].[Entity].[Entity ID].MEMBERS,
  [Measures].[CountValueNEW] = 1 
)  
ON 1
FROM [My Cube];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried HAVING in a number of different ways, but none worked,  the HAVING in your reply above operated on the [Measures].[Count] and does not focus on the [Value 1] which is the one I want to filter, all attempts at using HAVING and FILTER in this manner resulted in the same original dataset returned since they all have a value for [Count]

Comment: hey, thanks, I should have clarified when I said [Value 1] I meant [Dimension A].[Dimension A].[Value 1], I don't have a [Measures].[CountValue1], I only have a [Measures].[Count]

Comment: Hmmm. Someone marked my answer down. It provides a good answer to the question so I'd love to know the reason why it has been marked down?

Comment: This works, thanks a million for your time and assistance, also I understand what you are doing, you created a measure on the fly (which I didn't know about) and then used that to perform the filter, outstanding

Comment: No worries. Creating measures on the fly is very common pattern in MDX. Feel free to hit the check/tick if you’d like to mark this as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like

```
Select ([Dimension A].[AttributeHierarchy1].[AttributeHierarchy1],{[Measures].[Value1],[Measures].[Value2]}) on columns,

filter([Dimension B].[EntityID].[EntityID],[Measures].[Value1]=0)
on rows 
from yourcube
```

However there can be an issue. For example your dimesnion has two values A and B, for a particular row , A,value1 =1  but B, Value1=0, this row will appear as A qulifies for it and B gets carried over.

Edit

Lets take an example I want to see Internet Sales for Bottles and Cages haveing sales more than 150$

My initial query

```
select 
([Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
)
on columns,
[Customer].[City].[City]
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

Result 
[image]

Now modify the query

```
select 
([Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
)
on columns,

filter
(
[Customer].[City].[City], [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]>150
)
on rows 
from 
(select [Product].[Subcategory].&[28] on 0 from [Adventure Works])
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, you are assuming that there are two different measures? there is only one [Count], this is either 1 or non existant, I want to filter on the value of the dimension, I've tried a bunch of filters but essentially I need the filter to refer to the value of the dimension and then on the value of the measure that refers to that

Comment: Note, there are so many values possible for 'Dimension A' that it is not practical to assign each of them a separate count or dimension